# Interaction on my app through google assistant

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk

I have an app that users use to pay for parking in my city.
I want to perform an interaction on my app through google assistant, like I say Ok Google "start parking for one hour", it should activate parking on user's registered vehicle.

How can I achieve this?
Is it possible with existing built-in intents or should I use something else?

Comment: What you probably want is to create an "app action". It is basically a deep-link into your app which is started by the Google Assistant:
https://developers.google.com/assistant/app

Comment: I see that google manage these built-in intents https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents/ 
I don't see an action useful for start a parking.

Comment: I always assumed that one is not limited to built-in-intents and could freely define own actions. Maybe I am wrong.